# Parse a custom date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Given a date in the following format '21 Jan 2017' what is the best way to parse it to a date in SQL Server?

I have seen `TRY_PARSE ( string_value AS data_type [ USING culture ] )`  but there is no culture that corresponds.

And it preferably copes with different formats as well, so I would like to

```
TRY_PARSE('21 Jan 2017' AS DATETIME USING 'dd MMM yyyy')
```

Is there anything to do that?

Comment: What SQL Server version are you running? Always good to include a tag for that.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
select convert(date, '21 Jan 2017', 106)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if below is what you are trying to achieve. See more details about culture values [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql)

```
 select TRY_PARSE('21 Jan 2017' AS DATETIME USING 'en-US')
```